# How to use font substitution in Word Online and Office 365 in general?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts, cloud

I'm trying to make a Word template for my company and we use a custom font in our brand assets, it looks fine when the font is installed but when we send the files to our clients it looks pretty bad depending on what font is substituted.

Do you know how I could choose which font will be used as a back up font ?

Lets say we're using Helvetica Black, I'd like to setup our documents so that Arial Black is used if they don't have Helvetica installed.
I know it used to be easy to do in previous versions of Microsoft Word for Mac and Office in general but since we went to Office 365 and Word online I can't find a way to do it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Office "Online" applications are basically crapware.  They are "light" versions of the full install applications. They are adequate for creating simple documents and viewing or doing simple edits of documents created on full versions of the application. They are missing most features. Specifically, they do not allow you to change font substitution nor font embedding.

So, basically, you have to work on the file in a full install of Word, rather than Word Online.

In the full version you have 2 options.  You can embed your custom font, if your purchase of the font gave you the right to do that (have to check if you can embed the font and if it is embedded can it be used to edit the document. Those are separate rights that have to be granted.)

Or in the full version you can define the specific font substitution you want Windows to use.  Pick a font that is commonly installed on most Windows versions so you know it will work.

[Fonts that are installed with Microsoft Office 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2800393)

[MS Typography, Fonts by product or family](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/)

If you don't get full answers in time, you can go to [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us), a user support forum sponsored by MS.

It has over a dozen sub forums for various MS products such as Office and Windows.

If you have bug reports, or want to submit a request for a new feature, the place to go is the "UserVoice" forum. MS has set up a bunch of subsites there. Real MS Staffers read all of the postings, and they even act on a few of them. Follow this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-desktop/ms-suggestion-box-sites-at-uservoicecom/7397119c-6d48-49e6-8d94-7bd0a50d214f) for a collection of MS UserVoice subsites.